# Passing arbitrary struct from C to LUA and accessing it

Tags: c, variables, struct, lua, arguments

This problem I'm facing involves 2 parts:

1. **Passing arbitrary struct from C to Lua function**. As an example, consider these 2 structs:

   ```
   struct Person{
     int age;
     char *name;
   };

   struct Paper{
     int width;
     int height;
     char *color;
   };
   ```

   I want to be able to pass them to Lua with a simple C function, like:

   ```
   template<class T>
   void call(T t){
      ...  (pseudo-code)

     check t:
        if Person, lua_getglobal(L, "sendPerson")
        if Paper, lua_getglobal(L, "sendPaper")

     for each element in t, check its type
        if integer, lua_pushinteger(...)
        if char*, lua_pushstring(...)
     ...

     lua_pcall(...)
   }

   Person p = {33, "David"};
   Paper A4 = {210, 297, "white"};
   call(p);
   call(A4);
   ```

   2) **Accessing it**. In the Lua side, how can I access those variables by their names?

   ```
   function sendPerson(p)
       print(p.age)
       print(p.name)
   end

   function sendPaper(p)
       print(p.width)
       print(p.height)
       print(p.color)
   end
   ```

   I know I can use `setfield`, but unless I could call it inside my generic method for calling Lua functions, I don't see how it's possible.

**UPDATE**: Here is the code. As an example, here's WM_LBUTTONDOWN event. Going this way, I need to have 2 methods and 1 struct for ever handled message I send to lua: first method for creating the thread, second method to call lua function, and the struct so I can pass it as an argument to the thread function.

```
struct LButtonEvent{
int x, y, k;
};

LuaScript *L = new LuaScript(FILENAME);

void _onLButtonDown(LPVOID arg)
{
    LButtonEvent *b = (LButtonEvent*) arg;
    lua_State *l = L->getState();
    lua_getglobal(l, "onLButtonDown");
    lua_newtable(l);
    lua_pushinteger(l, b->x); lua_setfield(l, -2, "x");
    lua_pushinteger(l, b->y); lua_setfield(l, -2, "y");
    lua_pushinteger(l, b->k); lua_setfield(l, -2, "k");

    lua_pcall(l, 1, 0, 0);
}

void LuaScript::onLButtonDown(LButtonEvent b)
{
    // I want my window to continue proccessing messages. If lua script calls "sleep", the window freezes.
    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) _onLButtonDown, (LPVOID) &b, 0, 0); 
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        LButtonEvent b;
        b.x = (int)(short)LOWORD(lParam);
        b.y = (int)(short)HIWORD(lParam);
        b.k = wParam;
        L->onLButtonDown(b);
        break;

    ....
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding the update: You are right, you have to define a lot of stuff. I can't really answer this any further, because i don't really know the window and callback mechanisms. However, in your first example, you show in pseudocode that you are passing some relevant data to lua. Why not pass exactly the values you need? This way, you can define the lua functions in the right manner (with the corresponding arguments) and don't have to access the values via a table.
I still, however, have the feeling this could be done easier. But this highly depends on your structure, and i don't know that.

Comment: I have the feeling you could use some kind of inheritance in your c++ code and having an appropriate, overloaded function for calling lua per class.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't differentiate between the two (or more) types by different functions. Use metatables! That way, you don't need to know the exact type, just use the only availabe function and it will do the right thing.

Here you can see how this can be done, but keep in mind that there are better ways to create and open the library.

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int create_person(lua_State* L)
{
    int age = lua_tointeger(L, -2);
    const char* name = lua_tostring(L, -1);

    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, age);
    lua_pushstring(L, name);
    lua_setfield(L, -3, "name");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "age");

    luaL_setmetatable(L, "personmeta");

    return 1;
}

int print_person(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "name");
    const char* name = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    lua_getfield(L, -2, "age");
    int age = lua_tointeger(L, -1);

    printf("Name: %s\nAge : %d\n", name, age);
    return 0;
}

int create_paper(lua_State* L)
{
    int width = lua_tointeger(L, -3);
    int height = lua_tointeger(L, -2);
    const char* color = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    lua_newtable(L);

    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, width);
    lua_pushinteger(L, height);
    lua_setfield(L, -3, "height");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "width");

    lua_pushstring(L, color);
    lua_setfield(L, -3, "color");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "dimensions");

    luaL_setmetatable(L, "papermeta");

    return 1;
}

int print_paper(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "color");
    const char* color = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    lua_getfield(L, -2, "dimensions");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "width");
    lua_getfield(L, -2, "height");
    int height = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    int width = lua_tointeger(L, -2);

    printf("Paper: { %d, %d, %s }\n", width, height, color);
    return 0;
}

int luaopen_llib(lua_State* L)
{
    // initialization

    // create metatable for persons
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "personmeta");
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "personmeta");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, print_person);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "print");
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    // create metatable for paper
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "papermeta");
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "papermeta");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, print_paper);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "print");
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    // create library table and store the creation functions
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushcfunction(L, create_person);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "create_person");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, create_paper);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "create_paper");
    return 1;
}
```

Lua code for testing:

```
local llib = require "llib"

local p = llib.create_person(33, "David")
p:print() -- Name: David 
          -- Age : 33

local paper = llib.create_paper(210, 297, "white")
paper:print() -- Paper: { 210, 297, "white" }
```

Of course, you need to name this library accordingly.

If you need to use userdata, you can use it the same way. Userdata can have metatables.

Comment: But I don't want to create them in LUA. In LUA I just want to access their variables, like width, height etc. Furthermore, I have dozens of structs. That's the point: do I have to make "create_..." methods for ever struct?

Comment: Well, you can always create them in c as well. The question is: why do you have so many different structs, which seem to have no common ground (paper and Person) (i know this is an example, but still).
If they *have* common ground, use some sort of inheritance.
Somewhere, somehow you will have to define all the single "create_..." functions (or at least something similar). There is no way around that.

Maybe you need to clarify, what *exactly* you want to do, not how. Then we can have a look at that. But i have the feeling that you are thinking too complex.

Comment: I'm trying to create a window callback handle (my example was just to make things more clear, but I ended messing things up). So, when my window receives a mouse event, C calls lua function "onMouse(m)" and LUA can use m.x, m.y, m.click. When it's a wheel event, C call "onWheel(w)", and LUA can use m.delta, m.pos etc. etc.

Comment: Do you pass the whole window handle to the lua function or just the relevant information? If you do the latter (which seems the case, considering your example) then you are assembling all the data by hand.
So its no problem to expand this a bit and build some userdata holding the information or a lua table (btw, its lua, not LUA).
But still, this seems not to be ideal. Could you update your example and show some real code (do not bloat it; Make a minimum *working* example). Then i can have a look at it.

Comment: Updated it! I'm passing just relevant information, but there's a lot of them.

Comment: To Test this example you need something like: 
gcc -fPIC -c metatable.c -llua5.3 -I /usr/include/lua5.3/  ; gcc -shared -o llib.so metatable.o